# Android httpget works on browser but not in application

Tags: android, google-maps, http-get

Im tring to do an httpGet from my android app but i get no respond , when i do the same httpGet from the browser it work. i also use the chrome extension Postman to test the URL that i'm sending and it works

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    if (mMarkerPoints.size() < 2) {

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

        drawMarker(point);
    }
    String Text = "My current Latitude = " + latitude + " Longitude = "
            + longitude;
    Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                SendQueryString();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(".............", "Error");
            }
        }
    });
    trd.start();

}

public void SendQueryString() {

    String url = //
            "http://sistemamedicointegrado.azurewebsites.net/Home/Ubicacion?latitud="
            + latitude + "&longitud=" + longitude + "&id=1".toString().trim();
    try {
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        Client.execute(httpget);
        Log.i(".............", "I am here"); 

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you have empty `catch` body. add `e.printStackTrace` there and take a look at the logcat to find the reason of error

Answer (score 2):

The **error** was on the server side, the action method from the controller wasn't allowing anonimus Gets.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask and call this method

```
public int getResponceWithGet(String url) {
      int code = 0;

    try {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);


     code=  rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return code;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("calling service", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("calling service", e.toString());
    }

    return code;
}
```

Comment: Take a look on the code, he executes request on another thread

Comment: He is not downloading or uploading large amount of data,then asyncTask would be better here.

Answer (score -1):

try this code!!!

```
public void SendQueryString() {

    String url = //
            "http://sistemamedicointegrado.azurewebsites.net/Home/Ubicacion?latitud="
            + latitude + "&longitud=" + longitude + "&id=1".toString().trim();
    try {
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpget);
        String result=response.toString();
         Log.i("Response", ":"+result); 
        Log.i(".............", "I am here"); 

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: why someone has downvote my answer i should know that.
what's wrong with above answer!!!

Comment: it's more like comment without any explanation. Moreover, you don't see what's inside `Client.execute`, maybe he prints response there

Comment: i got the same result

Comment: have you cheked your log ?